# Read byte values contained in file into byte array

Tags: java, android, arrays

If I have a file that contains the exact `byte[]` data that I want:

```
[-119, 45, 67, ...]
```

How can I read those values into a `byte` array? Do I have to read them as a `String`, and then convert those `String` values to `byte` values?

This is what I'm currently doing, and it works, but slowly:

```
BufferedReader reader = null;
    String mLine = null;
    AssetManager assetManager = CustomApplication.getCustomAppContext().getAssets();

    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(assetManager.open(fileName)));
        mLine = reader.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    String[] byteValues = mLine.substring(1, mLine.length() - 1).split(",");
    byte[] imageBytes = new byte[byteValues.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < imageBytes.length; i++) {
        imageBytes[i] = Byte.valueOf(byteValues[i].trim());
    }

    return imageBytes;
```

**UPDATE:** There seems to be a misunderstanding of what I want to accomplish. My file contains the EXACT byte data I want in my final byte array. For example, I want to convert a file with exactly

```
[-119, 45, 67, ...]
```

into a `byte[]` called result with

```
result[0] = -119
result[1] = 45
result[2] = 67
```

Answer (score 2):

`BufferedReader` is used to read `char` units. Use `BufferedInputStream` which reads `byte` units and use `ByteArrayOutputStream` to help you filling the byte array:

```
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(assetManager.open(fileName));
ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

int theByte;

while((theByte = bis.read()) != -1)
{
    buffer.write(theByte);
}

bis.close();
buffer.close();

byte[] result = buffer.toByteArray();
```

Comment: Reading the whole file by one byte after another is really bad and very slow practice.

Comment: This doesn't work. My buffer will contain the correct values `[-119, 45, 67, ...]` when shown as a string, but after `toByteArray()`, result contains `[91, 45, 49, ...]`. In debug, the string representation of buffer is correct, but the actual values are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Much faster version of Eng.Fouad code:

```
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(assetManager.open(fileName));
ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

int size;
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

while((size = bis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    buffer.write(buffer, 0, size);
}

bis.close();
buffer.close();

byte[] result = buffer.toByteArray();
```